# Get/retreive managed metadata column value from Document Library using SharePoint 2013 JSOM

Tags: client-object-model

I am trying to retrieve managed metadata column (NewsCategory) value in SharePoint 2013 Document library using JSOM. **I get "Object Object"** rather than actual value.

I tried:-

```
var newsCat = item.get_item('NewsCategory');

alert(newsCat); //Displays [Object Object]

var newsCatLabel = newsCat.get_label();

var newsCatId = newsCat.get_termGuid();
```

But, I get the error "Object doesn't support property or method get_label()"

I also tried :-

```
   var newsTags = item.get_item(' NewsCategory ');

   for (var i = 0; i < newsTags.get_count() ; i++) {

   var newsTag = newsTags.getItemAtIndex(i);

   var newsTagLabel = newsTag.get_label();

   var newsTagId = newsTag.get_termGuid();

   }
```

Even now I get the error "Object doesn't support property or method get_count()"

I have included " NewsCategory " in the load request:-

```
context.load(items, 'Include(File, NewsCategory)');
```

**Any idea what the issue is**? Do I have to add any *.js file using $.getScript?

I added following .js files

```
 var scriptbase = _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl + "/_layouts/15/";

$.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.Runtime.js", function () {

    $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.js", function () {

        $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.Core.js", function () {


        });
    });
});
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

It depends whether managed metadata column is a single-valued ([SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomyFieldValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn312518%28v=office.15%29.aspx)) or multi-valued ([SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomyFieldValueCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn312524%28v=office.15%29.aspx))

It seems in your case the type of managed metadata column is [SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomyFieldValueCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn312524%28v=office.15%29.aspx).

The following example demonstrates how to determine managed metadata field type:

```
var newsTags = listItem.get_item('NewsCategory');
var fieldTypeName = newsTags.constructor.getName();
```

From another hand, I guess there is a typo in your example at line:

```
var newsTags = item.get_item(' NewsCategory '); //why extra space in field name?
```

Try to replace it with this one:

```
var newsTags = listItem.get_item('NewsCategory');
for (var i = 0; i < newsTags.get_count() ; i++) {
    var newsTag = newsTags.getItemAtIndex(i);
    var newsTagLabel = newsTag.get_label();
    var newsTagId = newsTag.get_termGuid();
}
```

Comment: Actually space was induced when editing the Script. I face the same issue without space.

Comment: Could you please place the line: console.log(newsTags.constructor.getName()); after the line: var newsTags = item.get_item(' NewsCategory '); to print the type of the managed metadata field

Comment: The type "newsTags.Constructor.getName()" prints the type as string.

Comment: Thanks "Vadim" for your reply. The issue got resolved. I was using the wrong "listItem" object.

Comment: any advice how to do it by C#?

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1**: Get the Term Set ID-->

- Go to **Central Administration** > **Manage service applications** under Application Management > **Managed Metadata Service**
- Get the following field details: **Central Admin URL**, **Term Store Name**, **Group Name**, **Term Set Name**
  [image]
- Open the SharePoint Powershell using Run as Administrator
- Execute the following Script:

```
$taxonomySession = Get-SPTaxonomySession -Site ""
$termStore = $taxonomySession.TermStores[""]
$group = $termStore.Groups[""]
$termSet = $group.TermSets[""]
$termSet
```

- Get the Id. This is the TermSetID
  [image]
  **Step 2**: Fetch the Terms using JavaScript-->
- Go to your Site and in the Site Assets upload [jquery-1.11.1.min.js](http://jquery.com/) and Script.js. Script.js will contain following code:

```
var context;
//Term Store Name
var TermStoreName = 'Managed Metadata Service';
//Term Set ID
var PublicationId = '6dc72cb0-9ea2-4dbd-8559-1a3b555b2ca8';
//Array of Terms
var PublicationTerms = [];

function TermObject(termId,termName){
    var self = this;
    self.TermId = termId;
    self.TermName = termName;
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var taxSession = SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomySession.getTaxonomySession(context);
    var termStores = taxSession.get_termStores();
    var termStore = termStores.getByName(TermStoreName);
    var currentTermSet = termStore.getTermSet(PublicationId);
    context.load(currentTermSet);
    context.executeQueryAsync(
    function () {
        var terms = currentTermSet.get_terms();
        context.load(terms);
        context.executeQueryAsync(
        function () {
            var termsEnum = terms.getEnumerator();
            while (termsEnum.moveNext()) {
                var currentTerm = termsEnum.get_current();
                //Get the Term ID
                var termid = currentTerm.get_id();
                //Get the Term Name
                var termname = currentTerm.get_name();
                alert(termname);
                PublicationTerms.push(new TermObject(termid,termname));
            }
        },
        function (sender, args) {
            console.log(args.get_message());
        });
    },
    function (sender, args) {
        console.log(args.get_message());
    });
});
```

- Come to the page where you need to fetch the terms. Refer the following files

```
/_layouts/15/SP.Runtime.js" type="text/javascript">
/_layouts/15/SP.js" type="text/javascript">
/_layouts/15/SP.Taxonomy.js" type="text/javascript">
/SiteAssets/jquerygoo-1.11.1.min.js" type="text/javascript">
/SiteAssets/Script.js" type="text/javascript">
```

- Save the Page and check the result:
  [image]
  [image]

Best of Luck!!

Comment: Ranjan's Method worked for me.. but it gives me all Terms stored in my taxonomy term store group... I am customizing a document set docsethomepage.aspx and I need to get the metadata term of the displayed document set... How can I archieve this??